# сортировка массива по количеству чисел фибоначчи

Tags: c++, числа-фибоначчи

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fib(int number)
{
    int value = 0;
    if(number < 1) return 0;
    if(number == 1) return 1;
    return fib(number-1) + fib(number - 2);
}

int main()
{
    int row = 15;
    int column = 15;
    int arr[row][column];
    int arrQuantity[15];

    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            arr[i][j] = rand()%100-50;
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        arrQuantity[i] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < column; k++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
                if(arr[i][k] == fib(j))
                    arrQuantity[i] +=1;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "Кількість чисел Фібоначчі: " ;

    for(int i = 0; i < column; i++)
        cout << arrQuantity[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < column; i++){
        if(arrQuantity[i] > arrQuantity[i + 1]){
            for(int j = 0; j < row; j++){
                swap(arr[i][j], arr[i + 1][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "\n\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < column; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Нужно улучшить программу. Смысл программы в том, чтобы отсортировать столбцы массива по количеству в столбцах чисел Фибоначчи. Сортировать нужно по возрастанию, то есть слева направо.

Comment: В каком смысле улучшить? Если программа работает, что в ней недостаточно хорошо?

Comment: @VladD, видимо тем, что в ней нет сортировки...

Comment: @avp: Тогда это какое-то новое, неизвестное мне значение слова «улучшить».

Comment: @VladD, похоже, по скромности своей, ТС забыл добавить *кардинально*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int fib(int number)

{
int value = 0;
if(number < 1) return 0;
if(number == 1) return 1;
return fib(number-1) + fib(number - 2);
}

int main()
{
int row = 10;
int column = 10;
int arr[row][column];
int arrQuantity[10];
for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < row; j++){
    arr[i][j] = rand()%100-50;
}
}
for(int i = 0; i < column;i++){
for(int j = 0; j < row;j++){
    cout << arr[j][i] << "\t";
}
    cout << endl;
}
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
arrQuantity[i] = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < column; k++)
{

    for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
        if(arr[i][k] == fib(j))
        arrQuantity[i] +=1;
     }
}
}
cout << "Кількість чисел Фібоначчі: " ;
for(int i = 0; i < column; i++)
  cout << arrQuantity[i];
check:
for(int i = 0; i < column; i++){
if(arrQuantity[i] < arrQuantity[i + 1]){
        for(int j = 0; j < row; j++){
            swap(arr[i][j], arr[i + 1][j]);
    }
swap(arrQuantity[i], arrQuantity[i+1]);
goto check;
}
}
cout << "\n\n\n";

for (int i = 0; i < column; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < row; j++)
    cout << arr[j][i] << "\t";
cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```